# jQuery | Using jQuery to display a value on text changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have made a jQuery function to change the text of a readonly (not sure if this could be why, didn't work on not readonly) text input field, my code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stake").textchanged(function () {
        $('#dynamic_return').style.display = '';
        $("#showdynamicreturn").value = $("#stake") * $("#__odds");
    });
});
```

Is the event correct or is something else wrong as this doesn't work? (I am using VS 2015 preview and it doesn't say it's wrong but it doesn't say it exists either...)

***Edit***
HTML code:

```
<form action="/sports/football/" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%;">Sport: </td>
                <td>Horse Racing</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50%">Participant: </td>
                <td>Whale Trail</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Market: </td>
                <td>Scottsville</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Time: </td>
                <td>15:40</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Odds: </td>
                <td>3/1<input type="hidden" value="" id="__odds"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Stake: </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">£</span><input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="stake" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="Stake" onblur="return estimate()"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display: none;" id="dynamic_return">
                <td colspan="10">
                    <center><input type="text" id="showdynamicreturn" placeholder="Estimated return" readonly=""></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center><label for="eachWay">Each way bet?&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" id="eachWay" name="eachWay"></center>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center><input type="submit" name="submitTo__OpenBets" value="Open Bet"></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Hidden fields for the horses information. -->
            <input type="hidden" name="betslip_id" value="34"><input type="hidden" name="sport" value="football"><input type="hidden" name="odds" value="3/1"><input type="hidden" name="sport" value="Horse Racing"><input type="hidden" name="bettilldate" value="2015-05-13"><input type="hidden" name="bettilltime" value="15:40:00"><!-- Area to "submit a delete" and remove an item from the bet slip. --><tr>
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <center><input type="submit" name="delete_betslip_item" value="Delete this bet"></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Also add your `html` code

Comment: What is `textchanged`? Did you mean [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/)?

Comment: Is it intended to mix both Jquery and Javascript syntax in our computation ?

Comment: `textchanged` is neither standard javascript nor in the jquery library.

Comment: are you sure you are using jQuery while not raw js?

Comment: Not entirely sure there @zairwolf....

Comment: I have never used JavaScript or jQuery much before this, it is my first venture into it really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it, with help from the community of course:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stake").on('change', function () {
        var newVal = (parseFloat($("#stake").val(), 10) * parseFloat($('#__odds').val(), 10)) + parseFloat($("#stake").val(), 10);
        $("#showdynamicreturn").val(parseFloat(newVal).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Also - removed the `show()` from the equation as this was unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

First, in your html, you do NOT have any element with id "stake".

Second, if you want to do this, use jQuery method `on('change)` or `change`.

Comment: `<input style="width: 100%" type="text" name="stake" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" placeholder="Stake" onblur="return estimate()">` in HTML

Comment: Stupid mistake from me there! Thank you for pointing that out to me